# Making a bot in discord.py, how do I separate a user's data by guild?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, sharding

My bot has features like Health Points for each member of the guild that changes through commands. However, if a member is in multiple guilds all using the bot, their Health Points aren't separated from each guild (ie. if you have 23HP in one server, you also have this in the others). I want to make it so that the member's HP and all other data is independent from their data in another guild, how can I do this?

I've looked at sharding, but to be honest I don't understand a single bit of it. It sounds like a good idea, but I don't even know where to start.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you tell me how you store that member data?

Comment: It's in a list of lists, containing every single person in a server that uses the bot

Answer (score 0):

Sharding is not related to this problem, it is a way to host your bot on a large number of guilds. As you haven't explained the specifics of how you store your data, it's hard to give specifics. If you're using a simple key-value store, you could do something like `{guild.id}-{member.id}`, or if you can nest keys, something like:

```py
{
    guild.id: {
        member.id: {}
    }
}
```

You may need to convert them to strings depending on how you store your data.

Comment: thanks! I'm storing my data in a big list of lists that contains every single user in a server that is using the bot. Probably not the most convenient

Comment: So you would probably want to move to a `dict` like I showed which would improve lookup times and just make it easier to use